# Is it possible to create a custom css property and then get the value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

1, Can you create custom properties within css?

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="defaultOpenTile"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#defaultOpenTile {
    -myCustomProperty: 'helloWorld';
}
```

2, Using jQuery is it possible to get the value?

So far I've tried with no success:

```
var test = $('#defaultOpenTile').css('-myCustomProperty');
alert(test);
```

I've created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/x3cuT/

The reason I want this is because I have a website which needs converting to responsive desgin and I currently have some variables hardcoded in Javascript.

For example:

```
var animationDuration = 600;
var animationEasing = 'easeOutQuint';
var tileMargin = 40;
var tileTitleContainerClosedWidth = 320;
var triangleSize = 20;
var triangleAnimationDuration = 600;
var triangleAnimationEasing = 'swing';
var detailsClosedWidth = 300;
```

What I'd like to do is put these into a style sheet so that I can use media queries to set them based on the viewport. (I hope that makes sense)

Thanks!

Comment: What's a custom CSS property? Browsers typically ignore CSS they don't understand.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: why not use data attributes?

Comment: @AndyHolmes I've updated my question to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelBellamy: Use a language that compiles to CSS, like LESS, and you can use variables.

Comment: @Pete - sorry, I am using media queries which is fine for things like the height and width, but lets say on desktop I want the animationEasing to be easeOutQuint, and on mobile to be swing - how would I achieve that?

Comment: I can think of a couple ways to hack this together by using media queries to set a hidden object's properties and then in your javascript use a switch statement based on those properties.

Comment: Ah right you can just check the width with your js and then match the widths to your media query and change your animation depending on that or use css3 transitions in your css then you can just change the animation type in your media query

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought - I was hoping I could adjust everything using the stylesheet rather than various places. I.E Css - media queries and then if statements in javascript.

Comment: The browser ignores CSS extensions that it doesn't understand, but if you wanted to use the media queries to do your viewport testing, you could use a hidden `div` assign a style to and then test that style in your javascript using something like a `switch statement`.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/baacke/x3cuT/1/.

Comment: @baacke Thanks for that - I was hoping to keep everything in one place for ease of maintenance etc. But it looks like this maybe the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just store custom data in your element, you should use jQuery's .data() instead:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/